Разница множеств в Oracle с оператором minus
Есть запрос вида
select * from table1
minus
select * from table2

Таблицы довольно объёмные, необходимость обусловлена изменением данных в прошлых периодах, соответственно запросом находим добавленные\измененные строки. MINUS сортирует данные в TEMP (порядка 500Гб). Как можно решить задачу по-другому, чтобы избавиться от такой дорогой сортировки в памяти?
По БД Oracle 19c

Как можно решить задачу по-другому, чтобы избавиться от такой дорогой сортировки в памяти? Добавленные строки получить несложно - anti-semijoin по первичному ключу, это весьма быстро. А вот с изменёнными так не получится - вряд ли найдётся такой набор индексов, чтобы любое поле было префиксом в хотя бы одном из индексов. Но тут может помочь индексированное поле штампа времени обновления записи плюс первичного ключа - также anti-semijoin по нему. Ну и потом UNION ALL всего этого добра.

спасибо, anti-semijoin через not in\not exists? можно пример?)

Либо NOT EXISTS, либо LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL. На большой таблице второе предпочтительнее, хотя надо смотреть планы и сравнивать время на практике. Примеров - в любом приличном описании есть их...
